# Make changed in a dataframe from a function inside a function

Tags: r

R

I have a function inside a function. The inner function should make changes in a dataframe that should be saved in the dataframe for the outside functions as well. So it's the same dataframe, called df.

Here's an example. The value in cell `df[1, 1]` is 1 so running `fun1()` should convert that cell to 303 as it should first add 100 to it in the inner function and 101 should be saved to then be multiplied by 3 in the outer function. So it should return "303" but it returns "3" as it doesn't save the changes from the inner function to the df in the outer function.

(the "inner" function is created inside the "outer" function but I can't see how that would matter)

```
 df <- as.data.frame(1:5)
  
  
  fun1 <- function() {
    fun2 <- function(n) {
      df[1, 1] <- df[1, 1]+100
    }
    n <- 10
    fun2(n)
    df[1, 1] <- df[1, 1]*3
    return(df[1, 1])
  }

  
  fun1()
```

Answer (score 1):

R passes arguments by value. Please refrain from trying to change the object within the function ie languages that accept passing arguments by pointers and references do exactly this.

The best way to tackle this problem is to just store the inputs within the function with the same variable name. eg:

df <- as.data.frame(1:5)

```
fun1 <- function() {
  fun2 <- function(n) {
    df[1, 1] <- df[1, 1]+100
    df
  }
  n <- 10
  df <- fun2(n)
  df[1, 1] <- df[1, 1]*3
  return(df[1, 1])
}


fun1()
[1] 303
```

Yet `df` did not change. Its still the same

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach would be `<<-`.  According to its documentation,

> The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment

The OP's case is that it is a function and it is not clear whether the OP wanted to keep the original object untouched or not.  Assuming that we could change the original object, simply replacing the `<-` with `<<-` in the OP's function would get the expected output (no other changes are made)

```
fun1 <- function() {
  fun2 <- function(n) {
    df[1, 1] <<- df[1, 1]+100
   }
  n <- 10
   fun2(n)
   df[1, 1] <- df[1, 1]*3
   return(df[1, 1])
  }

fun1()
#[1] 303
```

NOTE: If we want to keep a copy of the original data, can do with

```
df1 <- data.table::copy(df)
```

before running the function

---

Or if we don't want the original object to be changed, create an environment and only modify the object in the env

```
 df <- as.data.frame(1:5)
fun1 <- function() {
   e1 <- new.env()
   e1$df <- df
  fun2 <- function(n) {
    e1$df[1, 1] <- e1$df[1, 1]+100
   }
  n <- 10
   fun2(n)
   e1$df[1, 1] <- e1$df[1, 1]*3
   return(e1$df[1, 1])
  }

fun1()
#[1] 303
```

NOTE: The OP's question is `So it should return "303" but it returns "3`.

Comment: Thanks! I should have put the creation of the df inside the "outer" functions as that's how it is in my case. But I can use your information anyway. So appearantly <<- changes "one step outside" so if I used it for the changes in the inner functions it makes the changes in the outer function which is what I wanted.

Comment: The thing is that this can have some sideeffects as it changes the data passed into the function